# How to implement Googlebot user-agent string?

Tags: javascript, mobile, googlebot

I'm trying to implement the Googlebot user agent string so I can give permission for google to check my mobile sites. I have a mobile_redirect.js file that is used for all my mobile site redirects. This is a two part question.

Firstly, will google pick up the the user agent in a javascript file?

Secondly, there are now two user agent strings:

The new Googlebot for smartphones user-agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

The Googlebot-Mobile for smartphones user-agent we will be retiring soon:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

How do I implement both of these user-agent strings into my .js file?

Comment: You need to do that in server-side, google doesn't execute scripts!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not totally clued up on this. Where and how can i implement the useragent's on the server-side?

Comment: all I can say: **In your server**. the rest needs more clarification on your side like your server, programming language ,...